# Can we automate a web appplication/mobile app without using element locators

Tags: automated-tests, saas, test-framework

This is shocking for me , one of the organisation offering service  ,they do automation without using any element locators through their own framework , and they are promising to support web, mobile iOS and android as well….
As a use you just want to define you BDD scenarios along with any one action like select, click,wait…

example:
I want to login and read an ebook

As a user I want to login
when i access one of the book
then I could read the book

here we need to provide
user name:
password:
book name 'select ' action

Is it possible handling test automation without using Xpath,css,id,tag…any locators?

if anyone have any information ,please do let me know…if this is correct then why we are using many locators, many tools…?

is it called SAAS model automation?

Comment: Consider rewording your question to make it clearer, add a link to the tool or framework that you're having issues with, what you're doing with it (eg. the actual code), the result you would expect or like, and the actual result you're getting. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I hope you understood that , it is about to know which strategy is good for implementing the framework…like using locators <selenium> and non locator< no having any idea on tools>, here its clear ..am looking for new automation setup for ebook reading test automation. its easy to decereasging rewards….but u have to understood all kinds of end users…dont expect everyone will come with expertise skills

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are other ways of

> handling test automation without using Xpath,css,id,tag…any locators

the simplest is through image recognition libs (like [sikuli](http://sikulix.com/)). Not optimal, but works like a charm.

Depending on how well

> their own framework

is architected, designed and implemented - it could [leverage the look&feel](http://automationisking.blogspot.com/2016/03/of-locators-and-bots.html) of the application. Meaning that such selectors:

```
//*[@class='medium-input-field']
```

become

```
//*[contains(@label, 'Your username here:')]//input
```

In simple words, the automation ties to the app UI design, not to the DOM.

As for this

> example: I want to login and read an ebook

most likely they are using some from of [DSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language). More info on how to implement this in BDD frameworks can be [found here](https://www.marcusoft.net/2013/04/PushTheHowDown.html).

Comment: Thank you, its really something interesting. let me know any tools which are preferable for this approach ,are there any frameworks to learn this approach. what are the dis-advantages if we follow this approach. how this is different form DOM….can't we miss any validations if we approach this strategy? how can we validate rendering data on each platform like 'web app','mobile app-like iOS,Android'…how can we trust this approach this as complete testing? When I can choose this approach?

Comment: Stackoverflow has a clear 'Thank you' policy. If you find an answer useful - upvote and/or select as best answer. As to all your  questions - I will try to be concise. Main tools - Sikuli, Selenium, Appium, Cypress, TestCafe, Puppeteer. How those are utilized and possible disadvantages - depends on a lot of factors (architecture, design, implementation, processes).  What approach and its delivery in testing to take is again a very broad, yet specific to your context topic. I would strongly advise you to take next step and hire a knowledgable and experienced person, who can take you beyond.